# What value to use for execution_count in code cells of iPython notebooks?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

What is the best value to use as an input argument for `execution_count` when generating an iPython notebook as a json file?

I understand it should be set to `null` but a json dump automatically puts quotes around it so I perform a search-replace after creation and remove these.  However ipython notebook still isn't happy with it.  I'm on Python 2.7, iPython notebook 4.0.5.

```
import json, fileinput, re

# Create the cell of python code
code_cell = {
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution count": "null",
    "metadata": {
        "collapsed": False,
        "autoscroll": False,
    },
    "source": ["import os\n", "import numpy as np"],
    "outputs": [],
}

# Create ipython notebook dictionary
nbdict = { 'metadata': {}, \
    'nbformat': 4,
    'nbformat_minor': 0,
    'cells': [code_cell]
    }

with open("test.ipynb", 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(nbdict, outfile)

# Strip double quotes from execution_count argument.  

file = fileinput.FileInput("test.ipynb", inplace=True)
for line in file:
    print(re.sub(r'"null"', 'null', line))
file.close()
```

The error I receive is `Notebook Validation failed: Additional properties are not allowed (u'execution count' was unexpected):`

This is even after I have `"execution count": null,` in the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an underscore: `"execution count"` should be `"execution_count"`, and then the `null` should work fine.